# Как конкретно Rest Api связан с Java

Tags: java, api

Как конкретно Rest Api связан с Java?

Нужно ли использовать какие-то специальные технологии или что-то ещё, чтобы приложение было Rest.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю именно то, как она связана с Java. Может, какие-то технологии под это заточены или что-то ещё.

Comment: Это не связано напрямую с Java. Это способ общения между клиентом и сервером, независимо от того на чем они написаны.

Comment: Именно это меня очень интересовало, спасибо большое. Если такие же есть пользователи как и я, то ваш ответ не был бы лишним.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [REST API, REST приложения: что это и с чем его едят? (+full)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519007/rest-api-rest-приложения-что-это-и-с-чем-его-едят-full)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С позволения insolor отвечу на свой же вопрос.

> Это не связано напрямую с Java. Это способ общения между клиентом и
>   сервером, независимо от того на чем они написаны.

Более подробно почитать про Rest Api можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519007/rest-api-rest-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-full)

Если insolor захочет написать ответ, то готов отметить его правильным.