# REST - это всего лишь набор правил?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, rest

В паутине много информации про https, но мало информации по REST с примерами. В основном статьи, которые я нашел по REST - это умные словечки и научные термины выстроенные в ряд.

Правильно ли понимаю, что REST - это всего лишь набор правил; если ты соблюдаешь эти правила, то получаешь правильную архитектуру? Но в таком случае можно вводить и свои условные правила - и что получается? Получается все равно REST, но уже с другими условностями. Можно привести какой-нибудь конкретный пример, чтобы можно было более четко составить себе картину?

Comment: REST это просто веб сервис, который использует http протокол. То есть данные передаются используя http протокол.

Comment: Да, вы правильно понимаете, что это набор правил. Да, можно вводить свои правила (главное чтобы они не выходили за рамки http протокола).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519017/258658 - вот тут, кажется, неплохо написано что такое REST с примерами

Comment: rest это просто методология(паттерн проектирования), как любой шаблон, его можно изменять и расширять, даже основные порождающие паттерны не требуют их беспрекословного соблюдения :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, `REST` - это всего лишь `паттерн проектирования`. Это некий удобный шаблон, который помогает всем разработчикам работать по "одним правилам". Есть некоторые базовые понятия и правила, но при этом нам никто не запрещает расширять этот набор своими "правилами"(в рамках `http-протокола`). Для получения более глубоких знаний рекомендую познакомиться с `http-протоколом`, с принципами взаимодействия `клиент-сервера`, и уже потом добавить к этому `REST-архитектуру`.